# JMeter: Writing to CSV causes an extra blank line to be written, but only sometimes

Tags: jmeter, performance

Using JMeter I have been trying to produce a CSV of the ID of all the database IDs that my web app creates. I'm simply looking to save one column of strings without any spaces, however when I do that I get inconsistent outcomes in the CSV file. Sometimes there are skipped lines and sometimes there are no skipped lines. I have tried working on this with JSR223 and Flexible File Writer but both give the same result, always the same issue. I thought there was whitespace or a line break in my variable but the debug listener indicates that is not the case (also when I remove the '\n' character from Flexible File Writer the entire output prints to a single line, so I think there are no line breaks present)

[image: output]

[image: file writer]

[image: json extractor]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this one just there now myself. Turns out I was setting the listener to listen to some other samplers in my test plan instead of just a single one, those samplers didn't have the ID property in a JSON response, so they output blank results, leading to blank lines being output. Solved, hope this can be of help to someone else in future :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's somehow connected with [scoping rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules), either your JSON Extractor tries to fetch a variable from another [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) or Flexible File Writer is listening to another Sampler when the variable is not set yet.

Make both direct children of the Sampler which produces this `id` and it should resolve your issue.

Alternatively add a [Debug Sampler or Debug PostProcessor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter) and see what are `createdRecordID` variable values for each step of your test using [View Results Tree listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree), most probably there is a blank value somewhere.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue, the penny dropped about 30 mins ago for me. Thanks for the help tho :)